# Reading big xml file

Tags: xml-parsing, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I need to read big xml file in Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9 SP2 desktop application.
Created cursor result which contains desired columns and convert.xsl file to transform xml to format readably by xmltocursor.

Tried

```
source = CreateObject('MSXML.Domdocument')
stylesheet = CreateObject('MSXML.Domdocument')
resultDoc = CreateObject('MSXML.Domdocument')
resultDoc.validateOnParse = .t.
stylesheet.load('convert.xsl')
source.load( 'bigxml.xml' )
source.transformNodeToObject(stylesheet, @resultDoc)

* Exception code=E06D7363
IF XMLToCursor(resultDoc.xml, 'result', 8192 )=0
```

But got

```
Fatal exception 

Exception code=E06D7363
```

at line

```
IF XMLToCursor(resultDoc.xml, 'result', 8192 )=0
```

and application terminates.

How to convert big xml file to cursor ?

XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>

  <!-- this replaces root tag with VFPData which is required from CursorToXML to work properly -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="VFPData">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this will denormalize XML data -->
  <xsl:template match="/ettevotjad/ettevotja">

    <xsl:element name="Document-Ariregister">

      <xsl:element name="nimi">
        <xsl:value-of select="nimi"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="ariregistr">
        <xsl:value-of select="ariregistri_kood"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="kmkr_nr">
        <xsl:value-of select="kmkr_nr"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="ettevotja_">
        <xsl:value-of select="ettevotja_staatus"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="asukoht_et">
        <xsl:value-of select="ettevotja_aadress/asukoht_ettevotja_aadressis"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="asukoha_e2">
        <xsl:value-of select="ettevotja_aadress/asukoha_ehak_tekstina"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="indeks_ett">
        <xsl:value-of select="ettevotja_aadress/indeks_ettevotja_aadressis"/>
      </xsl:element>
  
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- to ommit nodes data -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- to work over every node -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what does the content of XML looks like? And also xsl? Why would you make a transformation first (which is likely a filtering transformation that you might do later). Does it error if you directly try XMLToCursor() on bigxml.xml? How big is big? Did you also try with setting transformation to be sync instead of async (likely the cause of error)?

Comment: I can later test downloading the zip. In the meantime: source.async = .F.

Comment: Andrus, I made a quick check with your zip. XSL is faulty. I see why you are using XSL but instead you could use XMLAdapter.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. I added `source.async = .F.` before `source.load( cfn )`  but same exception still occurs

Comment: I also tried with XMLCursor and XMLAdapter. With small amounts of data XMLAdapter works atreat but as soon as you have some big data they are useless. I would go with the C# routine that I provided below.

Comment: This directory also contains csv file with same data. I changed application to read csv instead xml. nplaza code looks great. Calling it second time causes `_screen.oxml is not an object errror`. Using C# requires running .NET .exe or calling com object from VFP application which looks not reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using mxml.6.0., no need for xs file:

```
* requires msxml.6.0! ( https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=3988 )
*
Parameters fileName,xPath

fileName = "D:\Data\Xml\ettevotja_rekvisiidid_2021-01-27.xml"
xPath = '/ettevotjad'

xPath = RTRIM(m.xPath,1,'/')

Private All

    oxml = Createobject('msxml2.domDocument.6.0')

    Wait 'loading document...' Window Nowait

    With oXml As msxml.DOMDocument
        .Load(Fullpath(m.fileName))
        Wait Clear
        If .parseError.errorCode # 0
            Messagebox(.parseError.reason,16)
            Return
        Endif
    Endwith


Close Tables All

nsteps = 500
tini = Seconds()
Set Escape On

x =  1

DO WHILE .t.

    subset = oXml.selectNodes(Textmerge(m.xPath+'/*[ position() >= <<m.x>> and position() < <<m.x+m.nsteps>> ]'))

    IF subset.length = 0
        EXIT
    ENDIF

    cXml = ''

    For Y = 1 To subset.Length
        m.cXml = m.cXml + subset.Item(m.y-1).XML
    ENDFOR
    
    x = m.x + subset.Length

    Wait Textmerge('<<m.x-1>> records  << (m.x-1) / (SECONDS() - m.tini) >> records/sec ') Window nowait
    
    cXml = '<xml encoding="windows-1252">'+m.cXml+'</xml>'

    Xmltocursor(m.cXml,'xmlImport',Iif(Used('xmlImport'),4+8192,0))


ENDDO



Browse Normal Font 'consolas,8'
```

Comment: Depending on the xml file we should adjust the chunk size; for this one 500 node works best for me ( getting about 2.300 records/sec ).

Comment: edited: setting xmltocursor flag 4 ( preserve white space in data ) improves performance by 40%; refactor code to fix minor bug counting imported records.

Comment: Thank you very much. Running it second time throws error `_screen.oxml` is not an object

Comment: Hi Andrus, I kept the document loaded for testing purposes. In production we should get a new domdocument object and load the xml document before processing. I've edited the code to remove those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I like Marco's solution for at least it is in VFP. However, having big XML files like this, I would also care about performance. I tried with Marco's code and it took 80+ seconds to complete and may need some work if you really want those fields separated as in your XSL.

I tried, reading from that XML, transforming based on your XSL and writing to an SQLite database using C#. It took 7.2 seconds and those address lines were already separated.
Here is C# code if you would use anyway:

```
void Main()
{
    string dataFile = @"d:\Andrus\bigdata.sqlite";
    string constr = $"Data Source={dataFile}";

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    if (!File.Exists(dataFile))
    {
        CreateDatabase(constr);
    }

    InsertData(constr, @"d:\Andrus\bigxml.xml");

    sw.Stop();
    sw.Dump("Duration");

}

void InsertData(string connectionString, string xmlFile)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    using (SQLiteCommand sql = new SQLiteCommand(@"insert into MyData 
        (nimi, ariregistr, asukoht_et, asukoha_e2, indeks_ett, kmkr_nr)
        values
        (?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn))
    {
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("nimi", "");
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("ariregistr", 0);
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("asukoht_et", "");
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("asukoha_e2", "");
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("indeks_ett", "");
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("kmkr_nr", "");

        conn.Open();
        SQLiteTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))
        {
            r.MoveToContent();
            r.ReadStartElement("ettevotjad");
            while (r.Name == "ettevotja")
            {
                XElement x = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(r);

                string nimi = (string)x.Element("nimi");
                int? ariregistr = (int?)x.Element("ariregistri_kood");
                string asukoht_et = (string)x.Element("ettevotja_aadress").Element("asukoht_ettevotja_aadressis");
                string asukoha_e2 = (string)x.Element("ettevotja_aadress").Element("asukoha_ehak_tekstina");
                string indeks_ett = (string)x.Element("ettevotja_aadress").Element("indeks_ettevotja_aadressis");
                string kmkr_nr = (string)x.Element("kmkr_nr");

                ///
                sql.Parameters["nimi"].Value = nimi;
                sql.Parameters["ariregistr"].Value = ariregistr;
                sql.Parameters["asukoht_et"].Value = asukoht_et;
                sql.Parameters["asukoha_e2"].Value = asukoha_e2;
                sql.Parameters["indeks_ett"].Value = indeks_ett;
                sql.Parameters["kmkr_nr"].Value = kmkr_nr;

                sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            r.ReadEndElement();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
        conn.Close();
    }
}

void CreateDatabase(string connectionString)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    using (SQLiteCommand sql = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        sql.CommandText = @"create table MyData (
            nimi text,
            ariregistr number null,
            asukoht_et text,
            asukoha_e2 text,
            indeks_ett text,
            kmkr_nr text
            )";
        sql.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

PS: Code is run directly inside LinqPad.